# Google analytics doesn't show tracking of my App

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, google-analytics

I would like to Integrate Google Analytics Tracking into my IOS APP.

I have integrated Google Analytics Library and Add It To my Application.

Here is my code snippet,

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

   [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarHidden = NO;

    [GAI sharedInstance].trackUncaughtExceptions = YES;
    [GAI sharedInstance].dispatchInterval = 1;
    [GAI sharedInstance].debug=YES;
    [[GAI sharedInstance] trackerWithTrackingId:@"UA-43556575-1"];

    return YES;
}
```

Code In my `FirstViewController`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.trackedViewName = @"Home";
    ....
    ....
}
```

List of Librarys which i have added, (First i have copied all this library from download folder then added to my project folder and then in Xcode i am taking reference from project folder)

- GAI.h
- GAITrackedViewController.h
- GAITracker.h
- GAITransaction.h
- GAITransactionItem.h
- libGoogleAnalytics.a

Almost 5 days and still stuck with same problem :(

[image]:
**Please Help ...**

**Thank you for reading and thanks in advance.**

Comment: Check my answer in this : [stack link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18829584/google-analytics-in-ios-not-working/18829940?noredirect=1#comment28055770_18829940

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this may be one case.
 Your `UIViewController` class must be a subclass of the `GAITrackedViewController` class,

```
@interface FirstViewController : GAITrackedViewController
```

And Must override these function.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];
  self.trackedName = @"Home";

  // your code here
}

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
  [super viewDidAppear:animated];

  // your code here
}
```

As `viewDidLoad` and `viewDidAppear:` are important methods.

And Remember the profile must be for `mobile app`.

Comment: Yes My `FirstViewController` is subclass of `GAITrackedViewController ` and i also wrote `viewDidLoad:` and `viewDidAppear:` methods in my class

Comment: yes, i have created new profile in google analytics, i just tried this all code in new SampleProject it works but it doesn't works in my project. showing `duplicate symbol _GAILogDebug in` ERROR.

Comment: as i know `duplicate symbol` reason if you ncluded the `.m` file instead of the header `.h`

Comment: where should i check for duplicates ? means in which `ViewController` ?

Comment: I have included only `.h` files in all `ViewController`