# Google Analytics in iOS (Not Working)

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, google-analytics

I am trying to implement google analytics.. could you guys please help me

```
-(void) setGoogleAnalytics{

    // Initialize tracker.
    self.tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] trackerWithName:@"ipad app"
                                              trackingId:kTrackingID];

    NSDictionary *appDefaults = @{kAllowTracking: @(YES)};

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:appDefaults];
    // User must be able to opt out of tracking

    [GAI sharedInstance].optOut =
    ![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:kAllowTracking];

    // Optional: automatically send uncaught exceptions to Google Analytics.
    [GAI sharedInstance].trackUncaughtExceptions = YES;

    // Optional: set Google Analytics dispatch interval to e.g. 20 seconds.
    [GAI sharedInstance].dispatchInterval = 5;

    // Optional: set Logger to VERBOSE for debug information.
    [[[GAI sharedInstance] logger] setLogLevel:kGAILogLevelVerbose];

    [[GAI sharedInstance] setTrackUncaughtExceptions:YES];
}
```

and calling it in

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions{
            [self setGoogleAnalytics];
    //
    //
    //
}
```

Inside My ViewController implementation

```
 [self dispatchEvent:@"Purchase Done"];

[self trackViewName:NSStringFromClass([self class])];


 -(void) trackViewName:(NSString *) strClassName{
        [[GAI sharedInstance] defaultTracker];
        self.screenName=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",strClassName];
        [self.tracker send:[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:strClassName,@"ViewName", nil]];
        [[GAI sharedInstance] dispatch];

    }

- (void)dispatchEvent:(NSString *)strButtonText{

    id<GAITracker> tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] defaultTracker];

    [tracker send:[[GAIDictionaryBuilder createEventWithCategory:@"ui_action"     // Event category (required)
                                                          action:@"button_press"  // Event action (required)
                                                           label:strButtonText          // Event label
                                                           value:nil] build]];    // Event value  = [[GAI sharedInstance] defaultTracker];

    [[GAI sharedInstance] dispatch];
}
```

Which version of google analytics, I should download currently I have downloaded google GoogleAnalyticsServicesiOS_3.01.zip (Recommended) as I dont want to work with the beta version GoogleAnalyticsiOS_2.0beta4.zip

Comment: Just a note, you are setting trackUncaughtExceptions 2 times.

Comment: I hope that you've got already a working version of GA, but for sure, and for others, I've updated my answer for v3.

Answer (score 11):

UPDATE -- **Google Analytics SDK for iOS v3**

**So I'm using v3, and there is not any problem:**

I'm implemented it in the AppDelegate. In .h file:

```
#import "GAI.h"
@property (nonatomic,assign) id<GAITracker> tracker; // I'm not using ARC (assign)
```

.m:

```
#import "GAIDictionaryBuilder.h"
#import "GAIFields.h"

// GOOGLE ANALYTICS
[GAI sharedInstance].trackUncaughtExceptions = YES;
[GAI sharedInstance].dispatchInterval = 0;
tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] trackerWithTrackingId:@"yourGAID"];
```

And write a method like this:

```
- (void) sendGoogleAnalyticsView:(NSString*)viewName{
    [tracker set:kGAIScreenName value:viewName];
    [tracker send:[[GAIDictionaryBuilder createAppView] build]];
    [[GAI sharedInstance] dispatch]; // this will force track your views.
}
```

---

Old answer:

See this answer below this link, if you do it the same as I told in this answer it must work

[Another stack-overflow answered question about google-analytics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RnfJ9.png)

and use these methods:

```
[GAI sharedInstance].optOut = YES;
[GAI sharedInstance].dispatchInterval = 0;
[GAI sharedInstance].trackUncaughtExceptions = YES;
    tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] trackerWithTrackingId:@"YOUR TRACKERID"];


[tracker sendView:@"Your View name"];

[tracker sendEventWithCategory:@"YOUR CATEGORY" withAction:@"YOUR ACTION" withLabel:nil withValue:nil];
```

Download GoogleAnalyticsiOS_2.0beta4.zip from [this link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RnfJ9.png) this will contain those classes what you need, and it will work perfectly. Be careful, google analytics got a lead time, to show you information, about real time. And not real time datas will show only a day after

EDIT for 3.0:

I found some probably useful things for you:

> We have just come across this issue and this is slightly out of date
>   so here is an updated answer. The issue we were having after following
>   the instructions on the Google Analytics website, they instruct you to
>   add the following files `GAI.h`, `GAIDictionaryBuilder.h`, `GAILogger.h`,
>   `GAITrackedViewController.h`, `GAITracker.h` and
>   `libGoogleAnalytics_debug.a` library. What they completely forget to
>   include on the website instructions is the one where you have to
>   include `libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a` library. This is included in the
>   zipped download but there is no instructions to indicate to include
>   this in the debug version.
>
> Note : In the readme.txt `libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a` is just referred
>   to as `libGoogleAnalytics.a` Google have failed to update their
>   documentation to include the new name or the correct instructions that
>   indicate this is required in debug.
>
> Files and Libraries that most be included

```
GAI.h
GAIDictionaryBuilder.h
GAIFields.h
GAILogger.h
GAITrackedViewController.h
GAITracker.h
libGoogleAnalytics.a // Also know as libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a
libGoogleAnalytics_debug.a
```

[image]

plus information:

> I'm pretty sure google has not yet provided a arm64 version of their
>   `libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a`, which is really annoying ...it has
>   been weeks since the public the release of Xcode 5GM.
>
> For now, I guess only build for armv7, armv7s or remove google
>   analytics until they get their head out of their pants.

Here is a [iOS Getting Started Guide.](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/) for implement it.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
  // Optional: automatically send uncaught exceptions to Google Analytics.
  [GAI sharedInstance].trackUncaughtExceptions = YES;

  // Optional: set Google Analytics dispatch interval to e.g. 20 seconds.
  [GAI sharedInstance].dispatchInterval = 0;

  // Optional: set Logger to VERBOSE for debug information.
  [[[GAI sharedInstance] logger] setLogLevel:kGAILogLevelVerbose];

  // Initialize tracker.
  id<GAITracker> tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] trackerWithTrackingId:@"UA-XXXX-Y"];

}
```

To manually send a screen view, set the screen field values on the tracker, then send the hit:

```
// May return nil if a tracker has not already been initialized with a
// property ID.
id tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] defaultTracker];

// This screen name value will remain set on the tracker and sent with
// hits until it is set to a new value or to nil.
[tracker set:kGAIScreenName
       value:@"Home Screen"];

[tracker send:[[GAIDictionaryBuilder createAppView] build]];
```

Or Automatic Screen Measurement:

> Automatically measure views as screens using the
>   `GAITrackedViewController` class. Have each of your view controllers
>   extend `GAITrackedViewController` and add a property called screenName.
>   This property will be used to set the screen name field.

```
//
// MyViewController.h
// An example of using automatic screen tracking in a ViewController.
//
#import "GAITrackedViewController.h"

// Extend the provided GAITrackedViewController for automatic screen
// measurement.
@interface AboutViewController : GAITrackedViewController

@end


//
// MyViewController.m
//
#import "MyViewController.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@implementation MyViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Set screen name.
    self.screenName = @"Home Screen";
}

// Rest of the ViewController implementation.
@end
```

Event tracking:

[link](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/events)

> To send an event to Google Analytics, use
>   GAIDictionaryBuilder.createEventWithCategory:action:label:value: and
>   send the hit, as in this example:

```
// May return nil if a tracker has not already been initialized with a property
// ID.
id<GAITracker> = [[GAI sharedInstance] defaultTracker];

[tracker send:[[GAIDictionaryBuilder createEventWithCategory:@"ui_action"     // Event category (required)
                                                      action:@"button_press"  // Event action (required)
                                                       label:@"play"          // Event label
                                                       value:nil] build]];    // Event value
```

Comment: I have tried those things, but no luck. I want to tell you that i am working with GoogleAnalyticsServicesiOS_3.0.zip version as it is recommended by google.It does not have sendView method.

Comment: I still want to work with 3.0 version as it is in released phase. I don't want to work with the beta version for any application which is going to be release to app store with in 1 week

Comment: .Also when i created a new id it gives me the link to download the google analytics 3.0 sdk

Comment: I'm using 2.0 beta, and there is no problem with it. I don't know what s up with 3.0

Comment: I edited my answer I try to help you, I hope it will useful for you ! information is for 3.0 what you are looking for

Comment: I edited again, you can implement it from these inforamations.

Comment: `When this (optOut) is true, no tracking information will be gathered;`!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: "[[GAI sharedInstance] dispatch]; // this will force track your views" : this line save me today

Answer (score 11):

I had the same problem with 3.01. My problem was actually in the Google Analytics admin section.

I had a profile setup for mobile (which was actually setup as if it were a website) which worked with version 1.x. However it appears that Google has now implented "mobile" profiles as well. I believe that the 3.x mobile SDKs cannot track to "Web" profiles.

Create a new profile by following the instructions here. And then use the new tracking Id and it should start tracking.

Note: Do not set the dispatchInterval to 0, as others have suggested, this also prevented tracking, set it to 1. This fixed everything for me.

Comment: Thanks, worked on 3.03 as well. From Google's documentation: "If you want to track both apps and websites using Google Analytics, you must use different tracking IDs and separate properties. App tracking data can only appear in designated app reporting views, and web tracking data can only appear in designated web views. Alternative configurations are not supported and will result in corrupted or incomplete data." https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2587087

Answer (score 1):

In the **AppDElegate.m** file :

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "GAI.h"
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

   [GAI sharedInstance].trackUncaughtExceptions  = YES;

   [GAI sharedInstance].dispatchInterval = 1;

   [[[GAI sharedInstance] logger]setLogLevel:kGAILogLevelVerbose];

   id<GAITracker> tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] trackerWithTrackingId:@"TrackingId"];

   [GAI sharedInstance].defaultTracker = tracker;

   return YES;
}
```

In **ViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "GAITrackedViewController.h"

@interface FirstViewController : GAITrackedViewController


@end
```

In **ViewController.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.screenName = @"RED Screen";
}
```

Try it. This worked for me just fine. I tried it more than three apps. And All are working for realtime. If your account for **your app is new** then you might **have to wait** for 24h or more to see the result. Sometimes it take time to display realtime data without any reason.

Sometimes it also does not work because of old Google Analytics sdk. To get the latest sdk you can use cocoa pod. here is the procedure :

```
platform :ios, '10.0'
target “GoogleAnalyticsTestApp” do
   pod 'GoogleAnalytics'
end
```

Write these lines in your pod file in your project directory and save it. then install pod. To know how to install cocoa pod see the link :

[Error importing Google Analytics iOS SDK using Cocoa Pods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20206565/error-importing-google-analytics-ios-sdk-using-cocoa-pods/41805957#41805957)

Do not write Google/Analytics. Write GoogleAnalytics. Hope it will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@protocol GAITracker;
@interface GAITrackedViewController : UIViewController {
@private
    id<GAITracker> tracker_;
    NSString *trackedViewName_;
}
@property(nonatomic, assign)id<GAITracker> tracker;
@property(nonatomic, copy)NSString *trackedViewName;
@end

Paste this code on "GAITrackedViewController.h" file
Then you can use self.trackedName = @"Some Name"; easly.
```

Comment: This crashes for me. I'm on GAI 3.0.6