# Google Analytics with multiple UIViews on one UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, google-analytics

I'm trying to use Google Analytics to track screen flows. However, a few of our screens are multiple UIViews on a UIScrollView being controller by a UIViewController. I know that if you are using one UIViewController per screen, then you just set the tracked name for the UIViewController. Is there a way to do this for each visible UIView?

The screens are switched between by changing the y value of the content offset on the UIScrollView.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course you can do it another way, here is [another stack link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18829584/google-analytics-in-ios-not-working/18829940?noredirect=1#comment28055770_18829940)
I think your can find all informations there, but what you are looking for is:

> To manually send a screen view, set the screen field values on the
>   tracker, then send the hit

```
// May return nil if a tracker has not already been initialized with a
// property ID.
id tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] defaultTracker];

// This screen name value will remain set on the tracker and sent with
// hits until it is set to a new value or to nil.
[tracker set:kGAIScreenName
       value:@"Home Screen"];

[tracker send:[[GAIDictionaryBuilder createAppView] build]];
```